# Solana build error after twoxtx-setup.sh patch with 2x transaction size

Tags: solana-test-validator

Trying to test Confidential Transfers, so as i understand i need to use patched solana - https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/twoxtx-setup.sh

But during building this patched solana i got errors:
[image]

What i need to do to get working version of solana?

Comment: This was recently fixed, so be sure to pull the latest master from `solana-program-library`, blast the old `twoxtx-solana` directory, and try again.

Comment: Never mind, I was able to reproduce this, we need to make another change.

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/pull/3849 got you covered, but it seems like you already noticed the PR :-)